# Slow connection between AWS EC2 and MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following setup:
EU London
1x Loadbalancer
1x EC2

Asia Pacific Singapore
1x Loadbalancer
2x EC2
1x Mysql RDS

The app is a cordova app calling https endpoints which routes the call to the nearest load balancer based on the Geolocation routing policy in Route53. This is then routed to the EC2 instance in that region at which the data is then routed to the single MySQL RDS instance in Singapore.

Some of the endpoints between UK EC2 and Singapore MySQL RDS instance take about 10 seconds even though a traceroute between UK EC2 and Singapore MySQL RDS is 166ms. Just as a test I also called the same endpoint between Singapore EC2 and Singapore MySQL RDS which is 250ms so its definitely not the code.

Just as a test I also switched off UK completely so loading the app up in UK and calling the EC2 instances in Singapore is a lot faster.

So in summary:
Traceroute
UK to Singapore = 166ms
Singapore to Singapore = 15ms

Endpoint
UK to Singapore = 12seconds
Singapore to Singapore = 250ms

Where am I going wrong? What tools can I use to further look into the issue in the slowness between UK EC2 and Singapore MySQL RDS?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into setting up a read replica of your Singapore DB in London so you don't have to even deal with such a latency between your app in London and the DB in Singapore (at least for reads)? I would rather avoid having a DB to communicate with on the other side of the globe...

Comment: You almost certainly **do** have issues in your code where you are making multiple database queries.  It isn't likely a single query taking 10 seconds but rather multiple queries that add up.  You need to benchmark your code to identify the specific intervals to find the problem.

Comment: I have set up a read replica for backup purposes in London, but it's a social app with a newsfeed so it needs the DB to be live.